# MySQL Recursive SQL select takes too long to execute

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, recursive-query

I have a table with records that are referenced to their correlate records as "sponsors" of record and I am using this SQL select to obtain a list of 10 records:

```
SELECT A.ref_user_id, A.ref_user_id_sponsor, 
IF(A.businessname IS NULL OR A.businessname = '', LTRIM(RTRIM(CONCAT(A.name, ' ', A.surname))), A.businessname) AS namesurnamesponsor, A.level 
FROM ( 
with recursive parent_users (ref_user_id, ref_user_id_sponsor, name, surname, businessname, level) AS (
SELECT ref_user_id, ref_user_id_sponsor, name, surname, businessname, 1 level
FROM users_details
WHERE ref_user_id = XXXXXXXXX
union all
SELECT t.ref_user_id, t.ref_user_id_sponsor, t.name, t.surname, t.businessname, level + 1
FROM users_details t INNER JOIN parent_users pu
ON t.ref_user_id = pu.ref_user_id_sponsor
)
SELECT * FROM parent_users ) A LIMIT 10
```

but looks like it takes too long to extract just 10 records from a table of just 120 records total. Plus , I tried to create an index to speed up :

```
CREATE INDEX  idx_ref_user_id_ref_user_id_sponsor ON (ref_user_id, ref_user_id_sponsor)
```

but it takes too long even to create the index which would help the SELECT to give me back just those 10 results .
Do you have a suggest for that? An alternative Index? or even an alternative way to obtain upper 10 sponsors of selected record declared by `WHERE ref_user_id = XXXXXXXXX` ? Thanks to all! Cheers

EDIT : I run an EXPLAIN SELECT for the above query and I obtained this result:

[image: EXPLAIN PASTE]

and table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_details (
    ID bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ref_user_id bigint(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    ref_user_id_sponsor bigint(20) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,   
    sponsorship_code varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    name varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    surname varchar(250) NOT NULL,
    businessname varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
    activate tinyint(1),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT fk_users_details_id
    FOREIGN KEY (ref_user_id)
    REFERENCES users(ID)
    ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_users_ref_user_id_sponsor
    FOREIGN KEY (ref_user_id_sponsor) 
    REFERENCES users(ID)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

and a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users_details` returns just 120 records. The table `users` just contains ID, login, pwd and a couple others columns of the users

Edit 2 : Maybe is there a better SELECT to obtain same result concerning a list of the upline of an user referencing its sponsor? Or just would be better add a

```
CREATE INDEX  idx_ref_user_id_ref_user_id_sponsor ON (ref_user_id, ref_user_id_sponsor)
```

to speed it up?

Edit 3 :

here is a photo of 20 of those users.... obiously hiding sensible informations and as you can see ref_user_id and ref_user_id_sponsor are strictly connected between them :

[image]

and about the time of execution looks like no end time which is weird because some time ago with just some less data (like 60 users instead of 120) , that query gave me quickly enough 10 users result.
Eventually maybe is there an alternative recursive `SELECT` that would give me same result back just to check if could be that `with recursive` clause or not? Or even shall I have to create index on those two columns ref_user_id and ref_user_id_sponsor to speed it up?

Comment: And what tells EXPLAIN ??

Comment: HI @BerndBuffen I just edited my post with the EXPLAIN SELECT.... what do you think? thanks! Cheers!

Comment: Something is amiss if it takes too long to create your index on a table with 120 rows. Please [edit] your question to paste in the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE users_details` and also tell us the number of rows in that table.

Comment: Hello @O.Jones , I just updated the post with the CREATE TABLE , the count and explained what just contains in referenced users table

Comment: Two more questions for you: 1) can you provide some sample data? 2) how long is "too long"--how slow is this?

Comment: Hi again @O.Jones , I just added an Edit 3 section in my post explaining more with some sample data contained in the table

Comment: Is there a case of circular loops? This is a very common reason for a recursive cte to run forever.

Comment: HI @forpas , what do you mean having a case of circular loops? with this CTE select I just get first 10 uplines of an user and numbering them with "level" column

Comment: LIMIT 10 is applied after the query has returned all the rows.

Comment: @forpas , you were right! having a record that has SAME id in ref_user_id and ref_user_id_sponsor makes a circular loop as in fact you can see in the image for ID = 50! Thank you  a lot ! .... If you would evidence your answer where you mentioned circular loop so I can select as solution....  :-)

Comment: Fine if it is solved.

Comment: @forpas just a little quick question .... do you think creating an index on those two columns would speed CTE it when table will increase of users ?....